# SQL: Check if Table is subset of another Table

Tags: sql

Does anyone know how to Filter from two tables(A,B) all the tuples which are a full subset of the other table?

So I want to filter all the *matrnr* from Table A which contains both of the values of Table B.

So the result should be:
4321

Example:

**TABLE A:**

| matrnr | lvanr |
| --- | --- |
| 4321 | 1234 |
| 4321 | 4321 |
| 1234 | 5431 |

**TABLE B:**

| lvanr |
| --- |
| 1234 |
| 4321 |

Thanks for help :))

Comment: Is 4312 a typo?

Comment: no just an example value to fill the tables.. i wanna filter all the matricularnumbers which contains both lvanr of table B

Comment: In which case for the sample data no rows in TableA meet your criteria and your expected result is incorrect...?

Comment: Ah shit, there was rly a typo in it. Thanks haha :'D now it should be fine and make sense. sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

You can outer join the tables and filter on matching counts, does the following work for you?

```
select a.matrnr 
from TablaA a
left join TableB b on a.ivanr = b.ivanr
group by a.matrnr
having Count(a.matrnr) = Count(b.ivanr) ;
```

[Demo DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4f3094201594385aaadf0dc223884534)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. But to be honest I also dont rly understand how this works haha

Comment: Can you elaborate on why not, maybe I can improve it. You have not *tagged* a specific database but the above is standard SQL, can you review this [demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4f3094201594385aaadf0dc223884534) of it working using your sample data.

Comment: Andreas, modify the fiddle with sample data that demonstrates why it does not work. The query looks correct, so you need to demonstrate a setup where it does not